# If...Else If Statements for Comparing Numbers for 2 Different Conditions

Tags: javascript, html

I am having trouble verifying two conditions for my JavaScript. When I put in a number, The first `if` statement will work. However, the `else if` statement will not print out anything following that criteria. Some help would be appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>

<script>
function return() {
  var num1 = document.getElementById("num1");
  var num2 = document.getElementById("num2");
  var x = num1.value;
  var y = num2.value
  if (isNaN(x)) {
    alert("Please only enter numbers");
    return false;
  }
  if (isNaN(y)) {
    alert("Please only enter numbers");
    return false;
  }
  var calculation = (x + y) / (x * y);
  var result = document.getElementById("answer");
  if (calculation > 1) {
    result.value = "Your number is more than 1";
  } else {
    if (calculation <= 0.5) {
      result.value = "Your number is 1 or less";
    }
  }
}
  </script>
  </head>

  <body>
   1: <input type="text" id="num1"/>
   2: <input type="text" id="num2"/>
  <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick= "return()"/>
  <input type="text" id="answer"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What if the result is between `0.5` and `1`? None of the condition will be satisfied and nothing will be shown.

Comment: `var calculation = (+x + +y)/(x*y);`

Comment: `return` can not be function name..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You can not use reserved words as function names, variable names or labels.

Also cast input value as `Number`, [**`Unary plus`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) could be used.

---

`InputElement.value` return Value of type `String` hence if values are `2` and `3`, calculation will be `("2" + "3" ==> "23")`, values will be concatenated, not added!

Also note that you have a missing condition which is not handled, you should have else condition as well.

```js
function calculate() {
  var num1 = document.getElementById("num1");
  var num2 = document.getElementById("num2");
  var x = num1.value;
  var y = num2.value
  if (isNaN(x)) {
    alert("Please only enter numbers");
    return false;
  }
  if (isNaN(y)) {
    alert("Please only enter numbers");
    return false;
  }
  var calculation = (+x + +y) / (x * y);
  var result = document.getElementById("answer");
  if (calculation > 1) {
    result.value = "Your number is more than 1";
  } else {
    if (calculation <= 0.50) {
      result.value = "Your number is 1 or less";
    } else {
      result.value = "Unhandled condition!";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
1: <input type="text" id="num1" /> 2: <input type="text" id="num2" />
<input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calculate()" />
<input type="text" id="answer" />
```

Comment: And use `else if` in two places.

Comment: Second `isNaN`. Although not required as returned from inside of `if`.

Comment: What exactly is the purpose for unary plus (+x + +y)? I tried removing the unary plus for my function and it didn't work but once I used unary plus it worked?

Comment: @Rayon Thanks for explaining it! I understand it now.

Answer (score 0):

return is  statement, don´t use this as a functionname.

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        1: <input type="text" id="num1"/>
       2: <input type="text" id="num2"/>
      <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick= "returnq()"/>
      <input type="text" id="answer"/>
    <script>

    function returnq(){
      var num1 = document.getElementById("num1");
      var num2 = document.getElementById("num2");
      var x = num1.value;
      var y = num2.value
      if (isNaN(x)){
      alert("Please only enter numbers");
      return false;
      }
      if (isNaN(y)){
      alert("Please only enter numbers");
      return false;
      }
      var calculation = (x+y)/(x*y);
      var result = document.getElementById("answer");
      if (calculation > 1) {
      result.value = "Your number is more than 1";
      }
      else {
      if (calculation <= 0.50) {
        result.value = "Your number is 1 or less";
       }
      }
     }


    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

is ok...

sorry two answers at the same time

Comment: This didn't work for me. When I press calculate for a number less than 1, it will throw back nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The `else` statement is wrong try removing  `if (calculation <= 0.50)` like this:

```
    else {   
    result.value = "Your number is 1 or less";       
    }
```

Comment: I tried this method but it will throw back the result "Your number is 1 or less" even when the user doesn't put in a number.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're `return`ing which forces the function to exit, never giving the second `if` block a chance to run. Also, `return` is a reserved keyword in JavaScript and not advised to be a function name. [Link to jsbin](http://jsbin.com/qaqegahexe/edit?html,js,console,output).

Here's some code that would work:

```
  1:<input type="text" id="num1" /> <br />
    2:<input type="text" id="num2" /> <br />
  <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="sumUpper()" />
  <input type="text" id="answer" />

 function sumUpper() {
   var num1 = document.getElementById("num1");
   var num2 = document.getElementById("num2");
   var x = parseFloat(num1.value);
     var y = parseFloat(num2.value);
     var xError = false;
     var yError = false;

   if (isNaN(x)) {
     console.log("Please only enter numbers x");
     xError = true;
   }
   if (isNaN(y)) {
     console.log("Please only enter numbers y");
     var yError = true;
   }
     console.log(xError, yError);
   var calculation = (x + y) / (x * y);
   var result = document.getElementById("answer");
   if (calculation > 1) {
     result.value = "Your number is more than 1";
   } else {
     if (calculation <= 0.50) {
       result.value = "Your number is 1 or less";
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. Whatever number I put in I kept getting the else if statement result: "Your number is 1 or less."

Answer (score 0):

I guess the figures are being rounded up, showing both 1 and 0.5 as 1. If you must use the else, try a math function that would restrict the estimations.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use function name `return`. return is javascript keyword.

Try to something like this.

```js
function myFunction(){
  var num1 = document.getElementById("num1");
    var num2 = document.getElementById("num2");
    var x = num1.value;
    var y = num2.value;
    
    if (isNaN(x)){
     alert("Please only enter numbers");
     return false;
    }
    if (isNaN(y)){
     alert("Please only enter numbers");
     return false;
    }
    var calculation = (x+y)/(x*y);
    var result = document.getElementById("answer");
    if (calculation > 1) {
     result.value = "Your number is more than 1";
    } else {
     if (calculation <= 0.50) {
       result.value = "Your number is 1 or less";
     }
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
1: <input type="text" id="num1"/>
2: <input type="text" id="num2"/>
<input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick= "myFunction()"/>
<input type="text" id="answer"/>
```